# How do I perform a ledge-pull kill?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

While hanging from the top of a ledge, if an enemy is over the ledge, a ledge pull kill maneuver can be performed. I've seen the prompt momentarily and this has been performed against me, but I don't know how exactly to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You push the mêlée button to perform ledge-pull kills once an enemy is close enough.